# How do I do flavor specific tasks in a parameterized gradle build

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have a flavored android build and I am trying to run a task only when building a particular flavor.

in my Gradle I have

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 70
        versionName "4.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    productFlavors {
        def versionNumber = "4.0"
        unitTest
        up {
            applicationId "com.livelys.up"
        }
        down {
             applicationId "com.livelys.down"
        }
        strange {
            applicationId "com.livelys.strange"
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
        strange {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/strange/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/strange/res']
        }
        unitTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            assets {
                srcDirs = ['src/test/assets']
            }
        }
    }

}
def buildAliases = [
        'default'             : ['clean', 'assemble', 'testUnitTestDebug'],
        'up'          : ['clean', 'assembleUp', 'testUnitTestDebug'],
        'down'          : ['clean', 'assembleDown', 'testUnitTestDebug'],
        'strange'             : ['clean', 'doMagic', 'assembleStrange']
]

task magic << {
    File srcFile = file('src/partner/res/values/magic.xml')
    def content = srcFile.text
    def pcode = System.getProperty('Param1')
    def defaultLocation = System.getProperty('Param2')
    srcFile.text = content.replaceAll("%%%P1%%%","${pcode}").replaceAll("%%%P2%%%","${defaultLocation}")
}
```

I want to run Magic, if and only if I am building the strange flavor.  The params are fed from a Jenkins build script and are used to rewrite custom versions of the app.  I don't want to maintain a custom flavor for each custom version since that will become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Yo should go to Run -> Edit configurations..., click on add -> gradle

**Gradle project:** Enter your project name (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to see hint). Like `project:hello-world`
**Tasks:** Enter `:ProjectName:magic`, there's no hint. Like `:hello-world:magic` (Don't forget the colon at first!)